# Apache Spark , detect key change on a row and group rows

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-java

I have the below dataframe in spark where I need to detect the key change ( on column rec) and create a new column called groupId. For example the first row and second row belong to one group until again the same set of record (D) is encountered and 1st row and 2nd row belong to the same groupId.

```
rec    amount  date           
D        250     20220522                  
C        110     20220522                  
D        120    20220522                   
C        100    20220522                   
C        50     20220522                   
D        50     20220522                   
D        50     20220522                   
D        50     20220522
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
rec    amount  date            groupId   
D        250     20220522       1           
C        110     20220522       1           
D        120    20220522        2           
C        100    20220522        2          
C        50     20220522        2           
D        50     20220522        3           
D        50     20220522        4           
D        50     20220522        5
```

I tried many ways but couldn't achieve the desired output , I am not sure what I am doing incorrectly here , below is what I have tried

```
WindowSpec window = Window.orderBy("date");
 Dataset<Row> dataset4 = data

            .withColumn("nextRow", functions.lead("rec", 1).over(window))
            .withColumn("prevRow", functions.lag("rec", 1).over(window))
            .withColumn("groupId",
                functions.when(functions.col("nextRow")
                        .equalTo(functions.col("prevRow")),
                        functions.dense_rank().over(window)
                    ));
```

Can someone please help me what I am doing incorrectly here ?

Comment: Thanks much @vilalabinot, I tried the solution but it doesn’t work for a different variation of the scenario if the first row starts with C, then followed by D, C, D,C in the subsequent rows as it always thinks the first row is a different group

Comment: Edited the answer, good one, did not anticipate that

Comment: @vilalabinot sorry I am a java guy, trying to understand what does the below code do val different = if (df.rdd.collect()(0)(0) == "C") 1 else 0

Comment: df.rdd.collect() 'converts' the dataset to an array, then the first (0) gets the first row and the other (0) gets the first element of that row, so basically we are saying, `different` variable is 1 if the first value of `rec` is C

Comment: @vilalabinot I took the code changes, it still doesn’t work if the first row in the group starts with C and the last row ends with D

Comment: I did three use cases here: https://imgur.com/M0lmO2I , I think it is looking okay, if not, can you elaborate what is missing?

Answer (score 1):

Window function does not work quite work like that; here is a workaround that might not be the best one;

First, keep track of what the starting value is:

```
val different = if (df.rdd.collect()(0)(0) == "C") 1 else 0
```

We set a value of 0 to `C` and a value of 1 to `D`:

```
.withColumn("other", when(col("rec").equalTo("C"), 0).otherwise(1))
```

Then, we create a unique id (because we do not have a combination of rows that indicate a unique row):

```
.withColumn("id", expr("row_number() over (order by date)"))
```

Finally, we do a cumulative count:

```
.withColumn("group_id",
  sum("other").over(Window.orderBy("id").partitionBy("date")) + different
)
```

I partitioned by `date` here, you can remove that but the performance might degrade seriously. Finally, we drop `id`, final result:

```
+---+------+--------+-----+--------+
|rec|amount|date    |other|group_id|
+---+------+--------+-----+--------+
|D  |250   |20220522|1    |1       |
|C  |110   |20220522|0    |1       |
|D  |120   |20220522|1    |2       |
|C  |100   |20220522|0    |2       |
|C  |50    |20220522|0    |2       |
|D  |50    |20220522|1    |3       |
|D  |50    |20220522|1    |4       |
|D  |50    |20220522|1    |5       |
+---+------+--------+-----+--------+
```

Good luck!